# Kitchen water lines in the party wall. Is it a violation?

Tags: plumbing

My neighbor installed some copper lines running from bottom to ceiling in the party wall that separates up. The connectiond were originally already there since the two apartments share the same wall for the respective kitchens, but all the units in our condo have lines that run horizontally at knee level or so, going to the kitchen where the sink and faucet are.

the problem is my neighbor installed very long pipes from knee level to the ceiling, to create an "Arch" (imagine a shower where the lines go up to the ceiling (inside our common wall) then straight for 3 feet on her ceiling then down again to her sink)
I think her architect wanted to avoid having the copper pipes being an obstacle on the floor or at knee level.

The solution sure is pretty unconventional, but those wate rlines now are very noisy, because the entire wall resonates with the water flow, which I guess has to work harder to reach the ceiling and go back.

bottom line, I'm curious if it's a violation to use the party wall to install extra-long pipes, I think she should have installed them outside, on her side, because those lines create a lot fo noise (flow/stream high pressure noise)

what do you think?

Comment: "is it a violation" would depend on ***exactly*** where in the world it is (down to the town or city level) (the LAHJ as commonly shorthanded - Local Authority Having Jurisdiction) and possibly also on the terms of the deeds for the properties.

Comment: The problem shall be addressed to the condo association, which usually has rules (bylaws) regarding the use of shared structures. If you are a tenant, talk to the landlord.

Comment: How is this party wall constructed? That's a critical detail to this puzzle as well...

Comment: im the owner. the wall is classic drywall. the building was an old factory with high celings, and the party walls are basic drywall with water lines running low close to the floor and electrical wiring inside and insulation foam. nothing special

Comment: This is a common wall, as well as a load-bearing wall. If the new construction wasn't approved by your condo board, your neighbor is already in violation of the bylaws (which you should have on hand). So, find it out from your association, it is the proper channel to resolve this matter.

Comment: We still haven't a clue _where_ you live. Each of us could probably cite our local codes and ordinances, but they wouldn't do you any good because we probably don't live where you do.  Even if you tell us where (what city) you live, one of us would have to go look up the codes for you and that may not cover any condo/HOA type bylaws that would have to be considered, as well. Your best bet would be to take it up with your local building inspector

Comment: @Cent -- can you get us an *exact* stackup of what's going on inside that party wall? "Basic drywall" could describe a wide variety of assemblies...

Comment: i have no idea. it;s a wall where we have wiring, insulation and pipes..thats all i know

Answer (score 5):

First I’d look in your condo association agreement. When I lived in my condo we were required to submit plan showing materials used, etc. and how we will control sound between units to the association and get it approved before starting work. (Admittedly it was usually enforced for floor coverings, etc. ….no wood flooring without sound boards isolating the new floor.)

Second, I’d refer them to the Building Code IBC Section 1207.2.  It says, “Walls, partitions,  etc. that separates dwelling units shall have a sound transmission class (STC) of not less than 50 for air borne noise.” It specifically identifies penetrations, openings in construction for piping, bathtubs, etc.

Get familiar with what STC ratings mean. Google “STC rating chart” and you’ll see what is acceptable. If they don’t change what they did, I’d take it to the condo association and then the Building Codes Department. They have the authority to make them Change it. You can start here:

https://www.google.com/search?q=stc+rating+chart&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS900US900&oq=stc+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i512l2j0i433i512l2j5.4708j0j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=VKa7HTjDNaXj3M

Also, little known fact is that all contractors are required to be licensed in most cities and states they are working in. I’d call your state contractors builders board and see if they are licensed. They can mediate and tell them they need to remove it. If they don’t, the Board can use their bond to pay another contractor to fix it.